# Create a Table with Multiple Foreign Keys in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a `medias`, `projects`, `adds` and `agents` tables with `one to one` relationship as defined in this image:
[image].

I created the migration for the `medias` table like this :

```js
public function up() {
  Schema::create('medias', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table ->id();
    $table ->enum('type', ['PHOTO', 'VIDEO']);
    $table ->string('filepath');
    $table ->tinyInteger('position')->nullable();

    $table ->unsignedBigInteger('project_id')->nullable();
    $table ->foreign('project_id') -> references('id') -> on('projects') -> onDelete('cascade');

    $table ->unsignedBigInteger('agent_id') -> nullable();
    $table ->foreign('agent_id')-> references('id')->on('agents') ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('add_id') -> nullable();
    $table->foreign('add_id')->references('id')->on('adds')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table-> timestamps();
  });
}
```

I have a question : If for example i deleted a record from the `projects` table will i have an error because i have other foreign keys in the `medias` table ?

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:~:text=CASCADE%3A%20Delete%20or%20update%20the,or%20in%20the%20child%20table.) for more information about `cascade` means and usage. It will delete entire row, not a single field.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not get any error, Because you have define `on('projects')->onDelete('cascade')` in `medias` table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let try this.

> $table->unsignedInteger('need_id');
>
> $table->foreignId('need_id','agent')->constrained('monthlies');
>
> $table->foreignId('need_id','project')->constrained('projects');

In this code foreignId(column_name,'name_of_key').

hope this help